# Ruby on rails How to find first item in array that matches items in another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a leaderboard array that looks something like this:

`[{:member=>"1", :score=>7.0, :rank=>1}, {:member=>"5", :score=>6.0, :rank=>2}, {:member=>"4", :score=>5.0, :rank=>3}, {:member=>"3", :score=>4.0, :rank=>4}, {:member=>"2", :score=>3.0, :rank=>5}]`

I also have an array of active user ids `[3,5]`.

How can I get the member number of the highest ranked active user and assign that to a variable?  The leaderboard array will always be in order of rank.

Comment: When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e..g, `leaderboard = [{:member=>"1",...]` and `active_members = [3, 5]`. That way, readers can refer to those variables in text and code without having to define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
leaderboard = [{:member=>"1", :score=>7.0, :rank=>1},
               {:member=>"5", :score=>6.0, :rank=>2},
               {:member=>"4", :score=>5.0, :rank=>3},
               {:member=>"3", :score=>4.0, :rank=>4},
               {:member=>"2", :score=>3.0, :rank=>5}]

active_members = [3,5]

highest_ranked_active_member = leaderboard.
  select { |h| active_members.include? h[:member].to_i }.
  min_by { |h| h[:rank] }[:member]
  #=> "5"
```

Comment: I would expect '3' to be the return value here, as member '3' has the highest `rank` value of the `active_members`. Replacing `:min_by` with `:max` should fix that.

Comment: @pmannion, I wrote it that way initially but then it dawned on me that the lower the rank number the higher the rank. Rank 1, for example, is a higher rank than rank 2.

Comment: If I know leaderboard will always be sorted by rank, would `find` be the better option or should it not make a difference.  `highest_ranked_active_member = leaderboard(sort_by: :rank).find { |h| active_members.include? h[:member].to_i }`

Comment: I missed the last sentence of your question, so yes on `find`. If order is not known, sorting is unnecessarily expensive to just find a max or min.

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to reduce your array to only entries who's `:member` is also in the active user IDs array, and then take the first element of that array:

```
leaderboard = [...]
active_user_ids = [3,5]

leaderboard.take_while{ |m| active_user_ids.include?(m[:member].to_i) }.first
```

Comment: Since `leaderboard[0][:member].to_i #=> 1` and `active_user_ids.include?(1) #=> false`, `take_while` will return an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where I love creating reusable lambdas to reuse code when querying the data.

```
active_members = [3,5]
active_member  = -> member { active_members.include? member[:member].to_i }
member_score   = -> member { member[:score] }

leader_board = ...

# Find first active_member:
p leader_board.find(&active_member) #=> {:member=>"5", :score=>6.0, :rank=>2}
# Find active member with lowest and highest score:
p leader_board.select(&active_member).minmax_by(&member_score) #=> [{:member=>"3", :score=>4.0, :rank=>4}, {:member=>"5", :score=>6.0, :rank=>2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [
  {:member=>"1", :score=>7.0, :rank=>1}, 
  {:member=>"5", :score=>6.0, :rank=>2}, 
  {:member=>"4", :score=>5.0, :rank=>3}, 
  {:member=>"3", :score=>4.0, :rank=>4}, 
  {:member=>"2", :score=>3.0, :rank=>5}
]

list.select { |item| [3,5].include? item[:member].to_i }.max { |item| item[:rank] }[:member] => "3"
```